# Getting max value and index with max value at the same time from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
  Country  Year  Count
0     USA  2021   1500
1     USA  2018   6000
2   India  2019   3000
3   India  2021   5000
4      UK  2019   4000
5     USA  2019   3200
6   India  2018   5000
```

I want to print the following

```
Entry with Max count is (USA, 2018, 6000)

Country with max total count is: (India, 13000)

Entry with max count in each year is:
2018, USA, 6000
2019, UK, 4000
2021, India, 5000
```

The code below works.  But a couple of questions to see if I can do better

1. Any way to get maximum index and maximum value at same time instead of getting `maxidx` and then getting the values in it?
2. Any cleaner and simpler to get all the three quantities I want?

```
# Print (country, year, count) of the row with max count among all entries
max_idx = df['Count'].idxmax()
print("Entry with Max count is (" + \
      str(df.loc[max_idx]['Country']) + ", " \
      + str(df.loc[max_idx]['Year']) + ", " \
      + str(df.loc[max_idx]['Count']) + ")" )

# Print country with max total count and print (country, max total count)
country_sum = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Country', aggfunc=np.sum)
print("\nCountry with max total count is: ("\
      + country_sum['Count'].idxmax() + ", "\
      + str(country_sum['Count'].max())\
      + ")")


# Print country with max count in each year
year_country_groupby = df.groupby('Year')
print('\nEntry with max count in each year is:')
for key, gdf in year_country_groupby:
    max_idx = gdf['Count'].idxmax()
    print(str(key) + ", "\
          + str(gdf.loc[max_idx]['Country']) + ", "\
          + str(df.loc[max_idx]['Count']))
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output that matches the example

Comment: @mozway edited and added the expected output into the question

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your output like this:

```
# 1st output
cty, year, cnt = df.loc[df['Count'].idxmax()]
print(f"Entry with Max count is ({cty}, {year}, {cnt})")

# 2nd output
cty, cnt = df.groupby('Country')['Count'].sum().nlargest(1).reset_index().squeeze()
print(f"Country with max total count is: ({cty}, {cnt})")

# 3rd output
print("Entry with max count in each year is:")
for _, (cty, year, cnt) in df.loc[df.groupby('Year')['Count'].idxmax()].iterrows():
    print(f"{year}, {cty}, {cnt}")
```

Output:

```
Entry with Max count is (USA, 2018, 6000)

Country with max total count is: (India, 13000)

Entry with max count in each year is:
2018, USA, 6000
2019, UK, 4000
2021, India, 5000
```

**Update**
To get both max index and value, you can use `agg`:

```
idxmax, valmax = df['Count'].agg(['idxmax', 'max'])
print(idxmax, valmax)

# Output:
1 6000
```

Comment: @ArvindSwaminathan. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks yes, this looks great.  Two questions before I accept

1. Based on your answer it looks like there is no way to get both "max index" and "column values at max index" at same time (i.e you need an addition `df.loc` on the `max index`.  Is that correct?  if yes, can you add that your answer before the first print?

Comment: 2. ```cty, cnt = df.groupby('Country', as_index=False)['Count'].sum().head(1).squeeze()
print(f"Country with max total count is: ({cty}, {cnt})")```

From this solution it looks like it is guaranteed that when you call sum() the df will be sorted from the one with largest sum to least sum.  Is that correct?

Comment: According to your comment, I updated my answer. Can you kindly check it please?